# Need to get browser log. But "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error is occuring. How to clear this error?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get browser console logs using selenium webdriver - java. But code is getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error. How to clear this error?

This is my code

```
public class RandomDemo {
    static WebDriver driver = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        LoggingPreferences logPref = new LoggingPreferences();
        logPref.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPref);
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath+ "/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
        
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        extractLog();

    }
    
    public static void extractLog() {
        LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
        for(LogEntry entry : logEntries){
            System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp() + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Error which I'm getting is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.Date.(Unknown Source)
> at StudentTestScreen.RandomDemo.extractLog(RandomDemo.java:41)
> at StudentTestScreen.RandomDemo.main(RandomDemo.java:34)

Comment: I think you probably messed up your parenthesis when you try to create your date object.  You probably meant to use the Date constructor that accepts a long value and put your timestamp in it as in `new Date(entry.getTimestamp())`, but instead you try to create a date object by passing a string you generate by concatenating  `entry.getTimestamp() + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage()` together, which I doubt can be parsed to a valid date.

Comment: That beeing said, you should think about not usind java.util.Date at all and instead use one of the never java.time classes.